# Download an image and get its size - doesn't work with big sized images?

Tags: actionscript-3

The image is huge, the code does not work as intended - what is the problem with this code?

```
package {
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*
    import flash.net.*;

    public class something extends Sprite {
        public function something():void {
            var loader:Loader = new Loader();
            loader.load(new URLRequest('http://www.decidio.com/photos_company/small/83336.jpg'));
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(e:Event):void {
                trace(e.currentTarget.content.width);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

check if it fires `Event.INIT` and check bytestotal and bytesloaded on progress to see where's the problem.
also for big amounts of data i'd recommend to use `URLStream` class

**upd:** maybe it'd be better to add listeners before you start loading and to check `typeof(e.target)`